# MYSQL > inserting steam id in int(11) with nosteam account that seems to long

Tags: mysql

A friend of mine is asking me for help, he has servers for steam games. He uses a mysql data base and has a plugin on his game that stocks STEAM ID (ID of a player in game)

I've tested the data out of the game (STEAM ID conversion from 64bit to 32bit) and compare it to what is inserted in the db... the results are not equal...

Strangely an ID "2150032574" become in mysql data field int(11) "-2144934722"

I have tested all the code PHP and SMX in the game to verify all datas... and according to me (but i am not sure) it would come from the SQL and the relation of the data (ID) lenght and not from the code.

Could it be possible that the length of the ID is too big (maybe because of the unsigned ID value?) and is converted i don t know how into that negative value ?

And what could i do to fix this problem ? I imagined to change int(11) into a varchar(128) for example... but that seems so so so brutal and abnormal for me...

Please could someone help ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Signed `INT`s (the `11` does not relate to the max value the field can store) can store values up to 2147483647. `UNSIGNED INT`s can store values up to 4294967295. But since you wrote that you were getting a negative value after storing 2150032574, your field isn't `UNSIGNED` and so, can only store values up to 2147483647.

Assuming you don't have primary or foreign key constraints on your field, you could `ALTER` it to make it `UNSIGNED`, like so: `ALTER TABLE steamids MODIFY COLUMN steamid INT(11) UNSIGNED;`.

Comment: Great response ! with perfect explications !
What if i change the structure from int to bigint() ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is solved by simply change the structure of the field authId from int() to bigint()

ALTER TABLE  `DBTABLE` CHANGE  `FIELD`  `FIELD` BIGINT( 255 ) NOT NULL